# C++ property is none when accessed in bp

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints

I have a class in C++ that I want to access in BP. It appears to be fine in C++ but in BP I get Accessed None errors when I try to use it in BP. Here is the class declaration that I am trying to use in BP

```
UCLASS(BlueprintType)
class ZOMBIEHORDE_API UQualitySettings : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    // constructors

    UQualitySettings();

    // class functions and properties
};
```

I am holding on to it in the `GameInstance` as below so I can access it through the `GameInstance` reference.

```
CLASS(Blueprintable)
class ZOMBIEHORDE_API UZombieHordeGameInstance : public UGameInstance
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    UZombieHordeGameInstance();

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Zombie Game Instance")
    UQualitySettings *QualitySettings = nullptr;
};
```

And `GameInstance` .cpp

```
UZombieHordeGameInstance::UZombieHordeGameInstance()
{
    QualitySettings = NewObject<UQualitySettings>();
    ensure(QualitySettings);// this passes and does not throw an error
}
```

This shows how I am accessing it in a widget blueprint.

[image]

So how can it be that accessing `QualitySettings` in BP is `None`?

Comment: You've shown the code for `UZombieHordeGameInstance` but your blueprint code references `BP_ZombieHordeGameInstance`.

Comment: Have you tried pulling a Print String off of the Cast Failed execution pin of the Cast to BP_ZombieHordeGameInstance.  It may be that it's not even getting that far when trying to call the Quality Settings

Comment: I ended up doing a refactor of the code that avoids this. I never actually got to a solution.

Comment: You should try and give your UObject a UPROPERTY - The GC assumes all objects that inherit from UObject have one. Try adding `private: UPROPERTY() UQualitySettings* SelfRef = this;` in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the reflection system doesn't like the

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Zombie Game Instance") 
UQualitySettings *QualitySettings = nullptr; //try to remove the = nullptr from here.
```

Generally in UE4 we set the variables in constructor because of CDO and reflection system on-behalf.

Comment: I'll try but I would think since I'm setting the QualitySettings variable in the constructor and test its valid by calling ensure on it, that BP would see it as not nullptr anymore. Although I do know UE4 has a way of doing things sometimes that doesnt seem logical lol. I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: It was just a suggestion, although there is probably a reason noone uses the assign operator in var/property declaration (no where in UE4source as well).

Comment: I still get the error.